# Dynamically values parse to Popup Model Box from PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I was trying to parse the php data values which inside the while loop to the popup model .

#### Sample Code

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag="mixed" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';

mysql_select_db('levels');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db_server );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $id = $row['id'];
  
  ?>

<div onclick="showDialog('#dialog6');show_data();">

  <div id="getid">
    <?php echo $id; ?>
  </div>

</div>

<?php
}
mysql_close($db_server);
?>


<script>
    function showDialog(id){
        var dialog = $(id).data('dialog');
        dialog.open();
    }

    function show_data(){
      var x = document.getElementById("getid").innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
        
<!-- Popup Model -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog6" >
 <div id="demo"> </div>

</div>
```

Let's say if i have id => 1 to 10 , above code writing last 5 items from the table. which are 6 7 8 9 10 . ( it's working perfectly ) .

my requirement is to when i click the 7 it should parse 7 to the popup model. ( or let's say to the innerHTML of    ).

it only parsing the first value ( 5 ) . to all onclick events when i click the each number.

PS : this is test using mysql not mysqli or pdo :) .

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag="mixed" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';

    mysql_select_db('levels');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db_server );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      $id = $row['id'];

      ?>

    <div onclick="showDialog('#dialog6');show_data(<?php echo $id; ?>);"> <!-- Changed -->

      <div id="getid<?php echo $id; ?>"> <!-- Changed -->
        <?php echo $id; ?>
      </div>

    </div>

    <?php
    }
    mysql_close($db_server);
?>


<script>
    function showDialog(id){
       var dialog = $(id).data('dialog');
       dialog.open();
    }

    function show_data(y){ // Changed
     var x = document.getElementById("getid"+y).innerHTML; // Changed
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

<!-- Popup Model -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog6" >
 <div id="demo"> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mike ,
Thank you very much for the support given and really appreciate it.
It's working perfectly.

Comment: can you letting me know how to parse multiple values ? such as id , name and image ?

Comment: @RuwanRanganath, See my other answer. If you like my answer, please approve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try This One.

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");

    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM products WHERE tag="mixed" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';

    mysql_select_db('levels');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $db_server );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];

        ?>

        <div onclick="showDialog('#dialog6');show_data(<?php echo $id; ?>,'<?php echo $name; ?>','<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>');"> <!-- Changed -->

        <div id="id<?php echo $id; ?>"> <!-- Changed -->
        <?php echo $id; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="name<?php echo $name; ?>"> <!-- Changed -->
        <?php echo $id; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="image<?php echo $id; ?>"> <!-- Changed -->
            <img src="<?php echo $imgUrl; ?>" />
        </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }
    mysql_close($db_server);
    ?>


    <script>
    function showDialog(id){
      var dialog = $(id).data('dialog');
      dialog.open();
    }

    function show_data(id, name, imgUrl){ // Changed
        document.getElementById("dispID").innerHTML = id;
        document.getElementById("dispName").innerHTML = name;
        document.getElementById("ImgDisplay").src = imgUrl;
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Popup Model -->
    <div data-role="dialog" id="dialog6" >
    <div id="demo"> <!-- Changed -->
        <div id="dispID"></div>
        <div id="dispName"></div>
        <div id="dispImg"><img id="ImgDisplay" src="" /></div>
    </div>

    </div>
```